# In Objective C, is there a way to call reference a typdef enum from another class?

Tags: objective-c, scope, global-variables, enums, typedef

It is my understanding that typedef enums are globally scoped, but if I created an enum outside of the @interface of RandomViewController.h, I can't figure out how to access it from OtherViewController.m.  Is there a way to do this?

So...
"RandomViewController.h"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef enum {
 EnumOne,
 EnumTwo
}EnumType;

@interface RandomViewController : UIViewController { }
```

and then...
"OtherViewController.m"

```
-(void) checkArray{
      BOOL inArray = [randomViewController checkArray:(EnumType)EnumOne];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In OtherViewController.m:

```
#import "RandomViewController.h"
```

And you shouldn't name your variable like the type. Rather name it myEnumOne, or whatever you like :)

```
BOOL inArray = [randomViewController checkArray:(EnumType)myEnumOne];
```

Can you show us the declaration of the checkArray method? In my understanding it should be

```
- (BOOL)checkArray:(EnumType)blabla;
```

You shouldn't need to typecast the argument to EnumType when calling the method (I'm assuming that it's of the type EnumType already).

Comment: I am importing the header, but that doesn't seem to do it.  It gives me the error "EnumOne" undeclared.

Comment: Nevermind--typos are an amazing roadblock! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just import the header.